# jquery : jquery autocomplete clear text box if user does't select data from autocomplete list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my code :

```
$('#dr_name').autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "<?php echo base_url()."index.php/counter_sale/dl"; ?>",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                       name: request.term
                    },
                     success: function( data ) {
                         response( $.map( data, function(item ) {
                            return {
                                value: item.name,
                                label: item.name,
                                dr_id:item.data_id,
                                return flase;
                            }
                        }));
                    }

                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {  
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                $("#dr_id").val(ui.item.dr_id);
                return false;  
            } ,

         change: function (event, ui) {
            val = $(this).val(); 
              exists = ui.item.label==val ? 0 : 1;
              if (exists) {
                $(this).val("");
                return false;
              }
        },

        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 0        
    });
```

I use change event but it does not fire. can any body help me for give me a better salution. Actuly i want when user select data from list then data id is set to text box if he does not select anything then id box become clear.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is clearing text input when sending Ajax request and set "cache: false":

```
source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "<?php echo base_url()."index.php/counter_sale/dl"; ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                   name: request.term
                },
                 success: function( data ) {
                    //HERE
                     $(ELEMENT_ID).val("");
                     response( $.map( data, function(item ) {
                        return {
                            value: item.name,
                            label: item.name,
                            dr_id:item.data_id,
                            return flase;
                        }
                    }));
                }

            });
        },
```